# Pentax K-r: how do I turn off multiple exposure?

Tags: camera-settings, pentax, multiple-exposure

Multiple exposure: I know how to turn it on but how do I turn this function off?  I can't seem to get lower than 2.

Comment: Do you mean multiple exposure as in multiple images superimposed over each other in the same frame? Or multiple exposure as in the shutter clicks repeatedly and quickly when you hold down the shutter button (drive mode)?

Comment: The manual says to click the menu button twice to shut off the function, but this is not working for me either.

Comment: Maybe HDR or bracketing is activated?

Answer (score 1):

This is not a feature you turn off. You only use the *Start Shooting* action when you want to use it. After you have taken the selected number of shots, the camera stores the composite image and you are done.

When you shoot after the above completes, multiple exposure is off and it will shoot accordingly to the last drive mode selected.

Answer (score 0):

Hit the little Clock dial button to bring up the Drive Mode.  You will likely see the multi-image icon lit.  Tap back over to the single frame.

See Drive Mode on Link:
http://www.imaging-resource.com/PRODS/KR/KRA5.HTM